# Create and place buttons on Page_Load then bind them to a single event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a comment system using ASP.NET (C#), comments are stored in a XML file which is then, on Page_Load, formatted inside a div.

```
comments.InnerHtml += String.Format(
"<div class=\"comment_body\">" +
    "<img class=\"gravatar\" src=\"{0}\"/>" +
        "<span class=\"name\">{1}<strong class=\"date\">{2}</strong></span><br/>" +
        "<div class=\"rating\"> !Thumbs up, thumbs down, # thumbs up votes # and #thumbs down votes goes here</div>"+
        "<span class=\"message\">" +
        "{3}" +
    "</span>" +
"</div>"
, gravatar, name, date, message);
```

I want to insert 2 buttons/links inside the "rating" div, for each comment on the page. The two buttons are for Liking and Disliking the comment, how to I go about programmatically creating, binding them to an event and then checking what comment you clicked the button from?

Comment: Is it crucial, that you add your elements through 'InnerHtml'? Or would it be valid to use Controls.Add() for comments and each subsequent element? That would make it much easier...

Comment: The thing is, I don't know how to use it. Should I do some research on it then?

Comment: It's pretty simple. I'll give you an code example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code inserts two  nested divs into the page, and the adds two buttons to the inner div, and binds click events to each of them. In the event handling method each button can be identified by its id:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add comment div
        Panel pnl = new Panel();
        pnl.CssClass = "comment_body";
        form1.Controls.Add(pnl);

        // add rating div
        Panel pnlRating = new Panel();
        pnlRating.CssClass = "rating";
        pnl.Controls.Add(pnlRating);

        // button 1
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "uniqueId";    // here you set a unique id, which you can check in button click
        btn.Text = "Click me";

        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

        pnlRating.Controls.Add(btn);

        //button 2
        Button btn2 = new Button();
        btn2.ID = "uniqueId2";  // here you set a unique id, which you can check in button click
        btn2.Text = "Click me";

        btn2.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

        pnlRating.Controls.Add(btn2);
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        // identify the button by id
        switch (btn.ID)
        {
            case "uniqueId":
                break;
            case "uniqueId2":
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: With a bit a tweaking, now It works as intended and I learned how to use it. Thanks.